# window.Window is undefined on android stock browser

Tags: javascript, android

Iam testing the following code in various browsers. The primary objective being able to run this in the android stock browser.

I get valid outputs for both chrome and firefox on android, but the android stock browser shows "undefined" for alert 4, whereas chrome shows the output as function Window {[native code]}, firefox shows the output as [object Window]. Is there something iam missing here ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function diagnose()
{

    alert("1."+window);
    alert("2."+window.DOMImplementation);
    alert("3."+window.Node);
    alert("4."+window.Window);
    alert("5."+window.window);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="diagnose();">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```